# React Native: Creating an Animated View that slides directly with finger drag

Tags: animation, react-native

**Desired Effect:**

I want to create a basic animation of a smooth sliding `View` (left or right) in sync with the drag pace of my finger.(e.g. sliding an off- canvas menu into and out of view)

Currently I'm using `Animated.spring` in a parent component that handles all gestures. Then I'm using `transform`,`translateX` in a child component to slide a `View` left or right.

For Example:

**Root.js(Parent Component that handles gestures)**

```
_handlePanResponderMove(e: Object, gestureState: Object) {
    let dx = gestureState.moveX - this.state.swipeStart;
    Animated.spring(
    this.state.slideValue,
    {
        toValue: newValue,
        velocity: gestureState.vx,
        tension: 2,
        friction: 8,
    }).start(); 
}
```

**Navigation.js(Child Component that slides)**

```
render(){
    <Animated.View style={[styles.navigation,{transform: [{translateX: this.props.slideValue}]}]}>
        <View >
        </View>
    </Animated.View>
}
```

**The Problem:**

There is sticky/lagging behavior with animation instead of a smooth movement that paces the finger sliding guesture.

**My reasoning so far:**

From my limited Animation experience - `Animated.spring,` `Animated.ease` and `Animated.timing` don't really describe well the equally paced sliding movement I'm after - but I suppose I need to be using one of them to get  optimized native performance
(otherwise I'd just use  `.setState(slideValue)` and do some math with the current location of my finger to figure the position of the `View`.)

**Question:**

What would be the preferred way to describe this type of smooth sliding animation using the optimized React-Native Animated library?

**What I've tried out:**

1) Using `Animated.timing` and setting `duration` low and `easing` to linear(my best guess at what I should do)

```
Animated.timing(
    this.state.navSlideValue,
    {
        toValue: newValue,
        duration: 10,
        easing: Easing.linear

    }).start();
```

2) Moving up the `tension` on Animated.spring

```
Animated.spring(
    this.state.navSlideValue,
    {
        toValue: newValue,
        velocity: (gestureState.vx),
        tension: 300,
        friction: 30,
    }).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

The preset functions `timing`, `spring` are useful for running animations to a specified value with a given easing. If you want to tie an `Animated` value to an event, you can use [`Animated.event`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html#event) instead:

```
PanResponder.create({
  // on each move event, set slideValue to gestureState.dx -- the 
  // first value `null` ignores the first `event` argument
  onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([
    null, {dx: this.state.slideValue}
  ])

  // ...rest of your panResponder handlers
});
```